# ¿Que metodo debo utilizar para que un archivo de una base de datos se muestre en una tabla como link o como miniatura?

Tags: php

buen dia, estoy creando un pdo con php,pero nesesito que me cargue los archivos en una tabla sea en forma de link para abrir en otra pestañas o como miniatura, el problema que tengo es que cuando hago el llamado de la casilla en la tabla me trae el archivo en binario con todos los carapteres, lo que nesesito como ya mencione es que me salga en forma de link o miniatura para poder visualizar el archivo o descargarlo desde la misma tabla.

he intentado con href para convertirlo en link pero no me funciona simplemente me vuelve link todos los carapteres del archivo en binario se que no es muy complicado pero estoy estancado y como debe notarse es mi primera vez.gracias.

la celda a cambiar es la SD  ".$result -> SD."

```html
<tbody>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM biblioteca"; 
$query = $connect -> prepare($sql); 
$query -> execute(); 
$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

if($query -> rowCount() > 0)   { 
foreach($results as $result) { 
echo "<tr>

<td>".$result -> MATERIA."</td>
<td>".$result -> RAMA."</td>
<td>".$result -> NOMBRE."</td>
<td>".$result -> TEMAS."</td>
<td>".$result -> AUTOR."</td>
<td>".$result -> EDITORIAL."</td>
<td>".$result -> AYUDA."</td>
<td>".$result -> RESENA."</td>
<td>".$result -> OBSERVACIONES."</td>
<td>".$result -> SD." </td>  

<td>
<form method='POST' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='ID_BIBLIOTECA' value='".$result -> ID_BIBLIOTECA."'>
<button  name='editar' style='background-color: darkgreen' >EDIT</button>
</form>
</td>

<td>
<form  onsubmit=\"return confirm('Realmente desea eliminar el registro?');\" method='POST' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='ID_BIBLIOTECA' value='".$result -> ID_BIBLIOTECA."'>
<button name='eliminar' style='background-color: darkgoldenrod' >B</button>
</form>
</td>
</tr>";

   }
 }
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo mínimo de lo que se está produciendo y de lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: Disculpa si no me hice enteder, quiero que un archivo que tengo alojado en la base de datos como lonblogse muestre en una tabla, pero no logro que se muestre el archivo en este caso una imagen, si no que me muestra  los carapteres binarios del archivo ejemplo:  �� �q   !"#$%&.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato hay en SD, una cadena, BLOB, etc? No es buena práctica guardar archivos e imágenes en la BD, mejor guardar la ruta del archivo físico. Por otro lado, no es recomendable usar `$stmt::rowCount()` en selects ya que la BD no garantiza que va a devolver el numero de resultados. Si ya hiciste un fetchAll entonces solo basta con darle `count()` al array devuelto.

Comment: Ahora se entiende mejor, intenta con algo como esto: `$img='<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result->SD).'"/>';` Lo he creado así por claridad, te toca a ti incorporarlo en el contexto de tu código, metiéndolo por ejemplo en el `td` correspondiente. Para verificar si está funcionando, puedes hacer un `echo $img;` por ejemplo.